# Limit involving binomial coefficients: $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\binom{n}{0}\binom{n}{1}\dots\binom{n}{n}\right)^{\frac{1}{n(n+1)}}$

Tags: limits

I am facing difficulty with the following limit.

$$ \lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\binom{n}{0}\binom{n}{1}\dots\binom{n}{n}\right)^{\frac{1}{n(n+1)}} $$

I tried to take log both sides but I could not simplify the resulting expression.

Please help in this regard. Thanks.

Comment: Since $1\le \binom{n}{k}\le 2^n,$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}2^{\frac{n^2}{n(n+1)}}=2,$ this limit exist and should be a number between $1$ and $2.$

Comment: Seems to be approaching $\sqrt{e} \approx 1.648721271...$

Comment: @Bumblebee How to prove this identity,i.e,$1\le \binom{n}{k}\le 2^n$

Comment: @VenkatAmith: Binomial expansion gives us $(1+x)^n=\binom{n}{0}+\binom{n}{1}x+\cdots+\binom{n}{k}x^k+\cdots \binom{n}{n}x^n.$ At $x=1,$ we can see that $2^n$ is the sum of all binomial coefficients, hence must be bigger (or equal when $n=0$) than all of them.

Comment: oh, yes, I  forgot about that,
Thank you @Bumblebee

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We see that 
$$
\prod_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}=\frac{n!^{n+1}}{\prod_{k=0}^nk!^2}=\frac{n!^{n+1}}{\left(\prod_{k=0}^nk^{n+1-k}\right)^2}=\frac{H(n)^2}{n!^{n+1}}.
$$
where $H(n)=\prod_{k=1}^nk^k$. Now we see that
$$
\log(H(n))=\sum_{k=1}^nk\log(k)≥\int_{1}^nx\log(x)dx=\frac{n^2}{2}\log(n)-\frac{n^2}{4}
$$
as well as
$$
\log(H(n))=\sum_{k=1}^nk\log(k)≤\int_{1}^{n+1}x\log(x)dx=\frac{(n+1)^2}{2}\log(n+1)-\frac{(n+1)^2}{4}
$$
This gives
$$
-\frac{\log(n)}{2(n+1)}-\frac{n}{4(n+1)}≤\frac{1}{n(n+1)}\log(H(n))-\frac{1}{2}\log(n)=\frac{1}{n(n+1)}\log(H(n))-\frac{1}{2}\log(n+1)+\frac{1}{2}\log(1+1/n)≤\frac{\log(n+1)}{2n}-\frac{n+1}{4n}+\frac{1}{2}\log(1+1/n).
$$
As both the lower and the upper bound tend to $-\frac{1}{4}$ as $n\to\infty$ we get by the squeeze theorem
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left[\frac{1}{n(n+1)}\log(H(n))-\frac{1}{2}\log(n)\right]=-\frac{1}{4}\iff\\
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{H(n)^{\frac{1}{n(n+1)}}}{\sqrt{n}}=e^{-\frac{1}{4}}
$$
Using Stirlings approximation we notice
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n!^{\frac{1}{n}}}{n}=e^{-1}
$$
and thus
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left[\prod_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\right]^{\frac{1}{n(n+1)}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{H(n)^{\frac{2}{n(n+1)}}}{n!^{\frac{1}{n}}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{H(n)^{\frac{1}{n(n+1)}}}{\sqrt{n}}\right)^2\left(\frac{n}{n!^{\frac{1}{n}}}\right)=(e^{-1/4})^2\cdot\frac{1}{e^{-1}}=\sqrt{e}
$$

Answer (score 6):

Let limit be denoted as $L$,then $$\prod_{r=0}^{n}\binom{n}{r}= (n!)^{n+1}\left(\prod_{k=0}^n k!\right)^{-2} =(n!)^{n+1}\left(\prod_{k=0}^{n} k^{k-n-1}\right)^2= \dfrac{1}{(n!)^{n+1}}\left(\prod_{r=1}^n r^r\right)^2$$ Also we have the approximation  for [hyperfactorial](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Hyperfactorial.html)( the latter expression above )
$$\dfrac{1}{(n!)^{n+1}}\left(\prod_{r=1}^{n} r^r\right)^2 \\ \approx\dfrac{1}{(n!)^{n+1}}\left( A n^{\frac{6n^2+6n+1}{12}}e^{-\frac{n^2}{4}}\right)^2$$ using the Stirling approximation for $n!$ and simplifying we have $$L\approx \dfrac{A^2e^{\frac{n^2+2n}{2}}}{(2\pi)^{\frac{n+1}{2}}n^{\frac{3n+2}{6}}}$$ where $ A$ is  [Glashier-Kinkelin Constant](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Glaisher-KinkelinConstant.html)
and required we have and hence $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \sqrt[n(n+1)]{L} = \lim_{n\to\infty}e^{\frac{n(n+1)}{2n(n+1)}} =\sqrt{e}$$

Answer (score 1):

This should help simplify this problem, but I don't know how to get an exact answer and this is too long for a comment.

$$\prod_{k=0}^n {n\choose k}=\prod_{k=0}^n\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$$
Using $\prod_{k=0}^nk!(n-k)!=(\prod_{k=0}^nk!)*(\prod_{k=0}^n(n-k)!)$ and $\prod_{k=0}^n(n-k)!=\prod_{k=0}^nk!$ and $\prod_{k=0}^nk!=\prod_{k=1}^nk^{n+1-k}$, we can derive:
$$\prod_{k=0}^n\frac{n!}{(k!)^2}=\frac{1^n*2^n*3^n*...}{1^{2n}*2^{2n-2}*3^{2n-4}*...}=\prod_{k=1}^nk^{2k-n-2}$$
which gets you a nasty result according to Wolfram Alpha.

Answer (score 0):

##### Warning: The following argument is not rigorous.

We can rewrite the identity as
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}
\Biggl({n\choose1}\dots{n\choose n}\Biggr)^{1\over1+\dots+n}
= e.
$$
This says that, for large $n$, we have
$$
{n\choose 0}{n\choose1}\dots{n\choose n}\approx e^{0+1+\dots+n}.
$$
(I added the trivial terms ${n\choose0}=e^0=1$ so that the left-hand side would be the product of a row of Pascal's triangle.) Write $s_n={n\choose0}\dots{n\choose n}$. Then, since ${n\choose k}={n!\over k!(n-k)!}$, we can calculate
$$
\begin{align*}
s_n
&={n!\over0!n!}{n!\over1!(n-1)!}\dots{n!\over(n-1)!1!}{n!\over n!0!} \\
&={n!^{n+1}\over0!^21!^2\dots n!^2}.
\end{align*}
$$
And so
$$
\begin{align*}
{s_n\over s_{n-1}}
&={n!^{n+1}\over0!^21!^2\dots n!^2}
\Bigg/{(n-1)!^n\over0!^2 1!^2\dots(n-1)!^2} \\
&={n!^{n+1}\over 0!^2 1!^2\dots(n-1)!^2 n!^2}
\cdot{0!^21!^2\dots{(n-1)!^2}\over(n-1)!^n} \\
&={n!\over n!^2}{n!^n\over(n-1)!^n}\\
&={n^n\over n!}.
\end{align*}
$$

Aha! This means that
$$
\begin{align*}
{s_{n+1}/s_n\over s_n/s_{n-1}}
&={(n+1)^{n+1}/(n+1)!\over n^n/n!} \\
&={n!(n+1)^{n+1}\over n^n(n+1)!} \\
&={n+1\over n+1}\Bigl({n+1\over n}\Bigr)^n\\
&=\Bigl(1+{1\over n}\Bigr)^n\\
&\approx e,
\end{align*}
$$
so that $s_{n+1}\approx es_n^2/s_{n-1}$. We can now deduce the result inductively. Clearly $s_0={0\choose 0}=1=e^0$. Suppose inductively that $s_k\approx e^{1+\dots +k}$ for $k\le n$. Then
$$
\begin{align*}
s_{n+1}
&\approx{es_n^2\over s_{n-1}} \\
&\approx{e(e^{1+\dots+n})^2\over e^{1+\dots+(n-1)}} \\
&={e(e^{1+\dots+n})(e^{1+\dots+n})\over e^{1+\dots+(n-1)}} \\
&={e e^ne^{1+\dots+n}} \\
&=e^{1+\dots+n+(n+1)},
\end{align*}
$$
and we are done.

### References

Brothers, Harlan J., “Math Bite: Finding $e$ in Pascal’s Triangle”, *Mathematics Magazine* **85**(1) (2012), 51. https://doi.org/10.4169/math.mag.85.1.51