# $ \sqrt[n]{ \binom{n}{1} \cdot \binom{n}{2} \cdot \binom{n}{2} ........... \binom{n}{n} }$

Tags: binomial-coefficients

As a part of a limit question I was evaluating, it was required that I evaluate this sum. However I do know no easy closed forms of this.

I have tried applying the vandermonde identity but what is messing me up is the index of summation:

i.e:

$$ \sqrt[n]{ \binom{n}{1} \cdot \binom{n}{2} \cdot \binom{n}{2} ... \binom{n}{n} }  = \sqrt[n]{ \sum_{k=0}^{?} \binom{n}{k} \binom{n}{n-k} }$$

So, my problem is with finding '?' which is the top of the index of sum.

Comment: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2023222/limit-involving-binomial-coefficients-lim-n-to-infty-left-binomn0-bino/3739133#3739133), you are. This will be helpful

Comment: quite complicated answer

Comment: you may wish to tackle using stolz cesaro theorem, converting the problem as Riemann summation ( for easier and understandable  solution) or next way to tackle is using Bernes-G function which is similar what is explained in the given link solution.  I shall make update on it.  :) :)

Comment: As it stands *now*, a trivial lower bound is $n^{(n-1)/n}$, hence the limit is $\color{red}{\infty}$.