# Calculus Limits Problem (Homework)

Tags: calculus, limits

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \left[{\left({{n \choose 0}.{n \choose 1}.{n \choose 2}.\dots.{n \choose n}}\right)^\frac1{n^2+n}}\right]$$

I have tried to solve this question for a decent amount of time but with no avail,so I'd be grateful for any help provided.

ALSO:This may seem as a drag/nuisance, but are there any other alternate methods to solve this other than the one provided [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2023222/limit-involving-binomial-coefficients-lim-n-to-infty-left-binomn0-bino)?

Comment: can you show somethings that you have tried? also what calculus book is this from? page number and question number please.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Why do you call it a sum?

Comment: Maybe the answer is $ \infty $ ?

Comment: @jimjim I don't have a source for this question,it was listed as one of the questions in the homework assignment.

Comment: @Spectre I do not know the answer to the question so I wanted to know if this(answer being infinity) could be disproved.

Comment: Sorry, bro.... it was just a guess...

Comment: @Marktmeister I had tried your approach earlier as well,but then you end up with the answer as infinity.I'm not entirely sure of this answer as I had seen somewhere this answer being solved by double summation.